# Get path relative to executed flask app

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

In my flask app I recreate a sqlite database at every start.
For this I use code as shown on the [official webpage](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbinit/)

My project structure looks like this

```
project_dir/
|-README.md
`-app/
  |-StubbyServer.py (contains the flask root)
  |-schema.sql
  `- (all the other files)
```

Now my `StubbyServer.py` contains:

```
def get_db():
    db = getattr(Flask, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = Flask._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
        with open('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
        db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return db
```

If my working directory is `/path/project_dir/app` the command `python StubbyServer.py` works fine

If my working directory is `/path/project_dir` the command `python app/StubbyServer.py` fails with:

> File "app/StubbyServer.py", line 43, in get_db
>       with open('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'schema.sql'

I know why this happens but I don't know how I can work around this. 
I want my flask app to work fine independent from my current working dir, how can I achieve this?

Comment: By doing the right thing - have your app take a config parameter with a writeable dir where you keep your temporary files (or write in an OS-provided temp dir).

Comment: @pvg I am not sure what you exactly mean and how that should help. It is not about writing files it is about reading a specific file?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding this then. Aren't you talking about creating a new sqldb on every run?

Comment: Actually you are right, my database path is also using a relative one, so it will create a DB in the working dir. But fixing this would still not solve the problem of reading the schema. :(

Comment: The docs you are linking show reading the schema from the resource dir. Is there some reason you're not doing it that way?

Comment: @pvg Argh, you are right... I guess this will solve it. Tbh I don't know why I am not using open_resource :( Thanks. Do you wanna create an answer?

Comment: I just noticed that the other side of this - creating an ephemeral db file - is covered in the unit test docs http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#testing It's pure python so you can lift the relevant bit in your global app init code. This lets you avoid the potential negative security implications of having a writeable resource dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact use case happens to be the example used in the documentation for flask's `open_resource` [API call](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.open_resource) as well as the blueprint documentation linked in your question.

Specifically, the reference doc says:

> To see how this works, consider the following folder structure:
>
> ```
> /myapplication.py 
>      /schema.sql 
>      /static
>          /style.css 
>      /templates
>          /layout.html
>          /index.html
> ```
>
> If you want to open the schema.sql file you would do the following:
>
> ```
>  with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
>      contents = f.read()
>      do_something_with(contents)
> ```